# What is the better way to manage class instances within a factory?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory

I've got a "design" problem in a C++ project.

I have a class, named `Currency` (which can be `"USD"`, `"EUR"`, and so on..., and got some methods)
There are many instances of this class new-ed everywhere in the project, but there can only be a bunch of different currencies (~100).

So I wrote a method which allocates a `Currency` the first time it's asked, and returns an existing `Currency` otherwise :

```
    class Currency 
    {
    public:
      typedef std::map<std::string, Currency*> CurrencyMap_t;
    public:
      static CurrencyMap_t _currencies;

    public:
      static const Currency& getCcy(const std::string& name)
      {
        CurrencyMap_t::const_iterator it(_currencies.find(name));

        if (it == _currencies.end())
          it = _currencies.insert(std::make_pair(name, new Currency(name))).first;

        return *(it->second);
      }

    private:
      // can't instantiate from outside
      Currency();
      Currency(const Currency& other);
    private:
      // private ctor
      explicit Currency(const std::string& name) {... }
    };
```

So, now, I only have one instance of each different `Currency`.

But, I can't anymore have a class holding a `Currency` member, because the default-constructor is not defined :

```
    class CcyPair
    {
    public:
      CcyPair(const Currency& ccy1, const Currency& ccy2) {}
    private:
      Currency _ccy1; // won't compile because "no default-constructor available"
      Currency _ccy2;
    };
```

And I don't want to hold `Currency` pointers in `CcyPair` class.

Do you have a better way to implement such a "pattern" which ensures that if two instances of a class (here the `Currency` class) got the same attributes, then it's in fact the **same** instance (same underlying reference) ?

Comment: *Any* reason at all that you actually `new` the `Currency`? It doesn't seem like a big class, and with that there is no reason to `new` it.

Comment: because `Currency` class has no public constructor, so if I create a map holding `Currency` objects, it can't invoke the copy-constructor during the insert()

Comment: in fact, if I go with @kennbrodhagen's solution (which works for me), the only remaining problem is the automatic deletion of `Currency` objects at the end of the program. As I pointed out, I can't just hold `Currency` objects, I have to new() them... And I don't want to create an external Flyweight Factory with all the interfaces and such. So I'll go with a `std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Currency>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you did not want to hold pointers to the Currency objects, but how would you feel about holding a reference instead?  I'm not sure if you wanted to avoid pointers so you wouldn't be burdened by a lot of checks against NULL or if you had another reason.  Here is an example CcyPair using references:

```
  class CcyPair
      {
      public:
        CcyPair(const Currency& ccy1, const Currency& ccy2) 
          : _ccy1(ccy1), _ccy2(ccy2) {}

        CcyPair(const std::string& ccyName1, const std::string& ccyName2) 
          : _ccy1(Currency::getCcy(ccyName1)), _ccy2(Currency::getCcy(ccyName2)) {}

      private:
        // need to make these const since getCcy returns const 
        // you could also change the signature of getCcy to return non-const
        const Currency & _ccy1;
        const Currency & _ccy2;
      };
```

Comment: (with automatic deletion of objects using boost::shared_ptr<> in the static std::map)

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the Flyweight pattern. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

BTW with the flyweight you can also have a state associated but will have to filter that state out into a separate class.

Comment: yes, in fact the Flyweight pattern is more or like what I've implemented in my example.